# Coding Search Bar in Swift, one line of code messing me up

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am currently coding a search bar in swift using `Xcode`.  I have everything set up except the .`lowercaseString` method and the OutOfrange method. When I implement these methods it crashes.

I have tried using `.lowercased()` but it didn't seem to work.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredArray = tableData.filter({ (names: String) -> Bool in
    return names.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText.lowercaseString) != nil
})
```

The error message states

> "Value of type 'String' has no member  'lowercaseString'; did you mean
>   'lowercaseStringWith'?" and "Value of  type '(Locale?) -> String' has
>   no member 'rangeOfString'"

I expected
 this would fix case sensitivity but it just crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your filter parameter is of type `String` you can use the `range` function with options like this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredArray = tableData.filter({ (names: String) -> Bool in
    return names.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
return names.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
```

Answer (score 0):

You is using uncorrect syntax of `lowercased` function. Look the [offical docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641392-lowercased).

To use correctely it you must change it on `names` and `searchText` on your return line.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredArray = tableData.filter({ (names: String) -> Bool in
    return names.lowercased().rangeOfString(searchText.lowercased()) != nil
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect syntax. Please find below syntax with example.

```
let arrOut : [String] = ["ios Engineer","ilesh Panchal","Ilesh","iOS","ILESH","ilESH","Xcode","String","Swift"]
let arrResult = arrOut.filter({ (names: String) -> Bool in
     return (names.lowercased().range(of: "ilesh".lowercased()) != nil)  //.rangeOfString("date".lowercaseString) != nil
})
```

Here `arrResul` contains records `["ilesh Panchal", "Ilesh", "ILESH", "ilESH"]`.

here in your syntax need to correction with

```
return names.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText.lowercaseString) != nil
```

to below swift line

```
return (names.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil)
```

Happy Coding :)